# How can I find a definition true_user for Rails app using devise gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

After Rails 5.2 and ruby 2.6.5 upgrade, I am getting errors: (1) `NameError: uninitialized constant UserUploader::Uploader` and (2) `ArgumentError undefined class/module UserUploader::Uploader` when calling `true_user` within app/controllers/application_controller.rb.

Where can I find a definition of method `true_user` (I couldn't find any source for this method in the web)?

I am not seeing the relationship with `true_user` call and class `UserUploader < ImageUploader`.

Comment: Are you sure UserUploader::Uploader included on your project? If you think so, then add those code in your question.

Comment: You might try `grep -rn --color true_user .`
Keep in mind that methods don't always start with `def`. You may have a class method, which could potentially be declared with `self.true_user`

Comment: After further investigation, we found out that it was actually breaking at a conditional before the true_user call `session[:XX].present?`  That was related to old cache related to session information - user image cached through Uploader/CarrierWave.  We are currently trying to figure out what's the best way to deal with outdated cache.

Comment: If somebody lands here by searching `true_user`, it's probably because you are using the [Pretender gem](https://github.com/ankane/pretender) in your Rails app. So to answer your question @Jackie the definition of the method is [in the gem](https://github.com/ankane/pretender/blob/a0a3d50dba6c842e4dd6a0ed0bf8ecce94ad41a7/lib/pretender.rb#L25-L29)